# altering a list in a text file with Python

Tags: python, list, parsing

I am brand new to Python and am trying to alter a list in a text file. I'm taking a list from Oracle and want to add information to the list so I can paste it into a script. I would like to:
1. open the text file
2. for each line in the text file, concatenate it with some other text
3. rewrite the text file (or create a new one) to contain the new altered lines

ie.:
   if my list has these lines:

```
  -NorthAmerica
  -SouthAmerica
  -Asia
```

I want to rewrite the list with this text concatenated with it:

```
GRANT SELECT ON GEODATA. + line + TO GEO_VIEWER;
```

so it would ultimately look like this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON GEODATA.NorthAmerica TO GEO_VIEWER;
GRANT SELECT ON GEODATA.SouthAmierica TO GEO_VIEWER;
GRANT SELECT ON GEODATA.Asia to GEO_VIEWER;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Nothing so far... Have googled quite a bit but cannot find anything quite like what I'm trying to do... It seems very straightforward.. I'm not even sure how to open up the text file in a way that I can do a for loop to go through each line....

Comment: @Strider https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I would recommend:

1. Open both files using the `with` structure
2. Use a `format()` function to write the contents of file 1 into preset string, then into file 2

So the code elements would look something like this:

```
with open("file_to_be_read.txt", 'r') as fread, open("file_to_be_written.txt", 'w') as fwrite:
    for line in fread:
        fwrite.write("GRANT SELECT ON GEODATA.{} TO GEO_VIEWER;\n".format(line[1:]))
```

You may need to tweak the `format()` function a bit to get exactly what you want.  Right now it just does the whole line of `fread` except the first character.

Since you're new at this, here's some more in-depth explanation of what's going on:

The `with` structure is very useful when working with files, since it handles closing and a few other things.  This means with `with`, it is much less likely that you end up with errors because you forgot to close a file.  So,

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    #Do stuff
```

Is equivalent to,

```
f = open("file.txt")
#Do stuff
f.close()
```

In addition to making your code less error prone, it also improves readability.

The `format()` function is an incredibly useful (and slightly cryptic) tool for working with strings in Python.  The short version is that any `{}` within the string to which `format()` is applied, get filled with the arguments of the function.  So

```
print "Hello, my name is {}".format("Dave")
```

Produces

```
"Hello, my name is Dave"
```

Now, this is a silly example of course, but there is a huge amount of flexibility in the function.  There's even a whole [mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) for the formatting syntax!  You can use this for tables, producing fancy output, or all sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

You should include what code you have done so far and since you haven't done this, I am not going to give you the full code but the tools and skills you need to do this yourself.

Okay, so problem 1. Opening a textfile. When we do this, we have several ways we can open the file such as read, write, append, readwrite. If you want the full list, you can see it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm). For our job we need to read and write to the file. So we want Readwrite or (if you look on your table) `r+`. So first, let's do that.

```
with open('your_file_name.txt','r+') as file:
```

So we have our file opened. Now what?

We next need to read the file. Thanks to Pyhton's great dev's, we use an amazingly simply named function: `.read()`. So we have our file opened and saved in the variable `file`. Let's read it.

```
    countries = file.readlines()
```

But wait, I hear you ask, you said `read` and you've used `readlines`. This is because if we used `read`, we would have got a simple string but `readlines` will return us a list that we can loop through. Okay, so we have a list of strings that need to be written back to the file. So, let's do that. Surprisingly again we have a simply named function called `write.`

```
    for country in countries: #Loop through all the countries we just read
        file.write('GRANT SELECT ON GEODATA. ' + country + ' TO GEO_VIEWER')
```

This should do it, although you may want to play around with opening files in different ways. For example open one file by doing `with open('yourfile.txt','r')` and opening the one containing countries to read. Then, make a new file by using `with open('newfile.txt','w')` and then write them to this file! Play around! Hope I helped!